# change 1 year period to 30 days in laravel?

Tags: laravel

i have my laravel project which works like this:

system will calculate the profit per 1 year from start day of investment,
and add credit to user balance. how to change 1 year period to **30 days** (**or 1 month**)?

here is the code for 1 year bellow:

```
            public function boot()
            {
            View::composer('*', function($view){
            if (Auth::check()){
            $alert=Alerts::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
            $user=User::find(Auth::user()->id);
            $currency=Currency::whereStatus(1)->first();
            if(empty($user->image)){
                $cast="react.jpg";
            }else{
                $cast=$user->image;
            }
            $seen=Alerts::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('seen', 0)->get();
            $save=$data['save']=Save::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
            $profit=$data['profit']=Profits::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')- 
            >get();
            foreach($profit as $xpro){
                $profits=Profits::whereId($xpro->id)->first();
                $date1=date_create(Carbon::now());
                $date2=date_create($xpro->date);
                $date_diff=date_diff($date2, $date1);
                $start_date=date_create($xpro->date);
                date_add($start_date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 year'));
                $ndate=date_format($start_date, "Y-m-d H:i:s");   
                $profits->end_date=$ndate;
                $profits->save();
                if (Carbon::now()<$ndate){
                    $fdate=($xpro->plan->percent*$xpro->amount)/100 * (12*$date_diff- 
                 >format('%R%a')/365);   
                    $profits->profit=$fdate;
                    $profits->status=1;
                    $profits->save();
                }else{
                    $fdate=($xpro->plan->percent*$xpro->amount)/100 * 12;  
                    $profits->profit=$fdate;
                    $profits->save();
                    if($xpro->status==1){
                        $val1=$user->balance+$fdate;
                        $user->balance=$val1;
                        $user->save();   
                        $profits->status=2;
                        $profits->save();
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach($save as $xsave){
                $date1=strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
                $date2=strtotime($xsave->end_date);
                if(($xsave->status==0 && $date1>$date2) || ($xsave->status==0 && $date1==$date2)){
                    $save_amo=$user->balance+$xsave->amount;
                    $user->balance=$save_amo;
                    $user->save();
                    foreach ($save as $ss){
                        $ss->status=1;
                        $ss->save();  
                    }                   
                 } 
                }
```

Comment: Did you try to changing `date_add($start_date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 month'));`